# How can show limited number of years in the Datepicker Layout?

Tags: android, datepicker

Code: I want to show like 1990-1994 range in the Datepicker layout. I can set the range manually but I don't want users to see extra year fields. I'm using spinner mode for datepicker.

```
ActivityCalenderLayoutBinding calenderLayoutBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(this), R.layout.activity_calender_layout, null, false);
        final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert.setView(calenderLayoutBinding.getRoot());
        alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

               // calenderLayoutBinding.datePicker.setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis()-630720000000L);


                int maxYear = 1990;
                int minYear = 1998;
                int day = calenderLayoutBinding.datePicker.getDayOfMonth();
                int month = calenderLayoutBinding.datePicker.getMonth()+1;
                int year = calenderLayoutBinding.datePicker.getYear();

                if(year>=maxYear && year <=minYear) {
                    int age = java.util.Calendar.getInstance().get(java.util.Calendar.YEAR) - year;
                    hivselfRiskAssessmentBinding.ageNo.setText(new StringBuilder().append(age).append(" Years"));
                    }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Sorry you are not aligable ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    hivselfRiskAssessmentBinding.ageNo.setText("");

                }


            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the docs of [DatePicker](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker) you can find 2 methods that can control this:

1. [setMaxDate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#setMaxDate(long))
2. [setMinDate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#setMinDate(long))

Then before showing the `DatePicker`just do the necessary setup:

```
calenderLayoutBinding.datePicker.setMaxDate(123456789L);
```

The argument is the time since the January 1st, 1970 in the local timezone.

Comment: Thanks I was doing it wrong by calling it in wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
 and I am using same date for minimum and maximum change it as you want

```
DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogDatePicker);

 try {
        String dateString = "30/09/1994";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Date date = sdf.parse(dateString);

        long minimumDate = date.getTime(); 
        calenderLayoutBinding.datePicker.setMaxDate(minimumDate);
        calenderLayoutBinding.datePicker.setMinDate(minimumDate);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```